# How to add AdMob to Activity?

Tags: android, admob

I'm doing a new app. All is finished but I still need to implement a Admob Banner to the bottom of my app. I never did that before, so I wanted to ask if anybody can help me?

I already tried some things in tutorials on Youtube but nothing helped.

Here some example https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIgWp.png

Here my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mListNotes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListNotes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_create: //run NoteActivity in new note mode
                startActivity(new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class));
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //load saved notes into the listview
        //first, reset the listview
        mListNotes.setAdapter(null);
        ArrayList<Note> notes = Utilities.getAllSavedNotes(getApplicationContext());

        //sort notes from new to old
        Collections.sort(notes, new Comparator<Note>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Note lhs, Note rhs) {
                if(lhs.getDateTime() < rhs.getDateTime()) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });

        if(notes != null && notes.size() > 0) { //check if we have any notes!
            final NoteAdapter na = new NoteAdapter(this, R.layout.view_note_item, notes);
            mListNotes.setAdapter(na);

            //set click listener for items in the list, by clicking each item the note should be loaded into NoteActivity
            mListNotes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //run the NoteActivity in view/edit mode
                    String fileName = ((Note) mListNotes.getItemAtPosition(position)).getDateTime()
                            + Utilities.FILE_EXTENSION;
                    Intent viewNoteIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteActivity.class);
                    viewNoteIntent.putExtra(Utilities.EXTRAS_NOTE_FILENAME, fileName);
                    startActivity(viewNoteIntent);
                }
            });
        } else { //remind user that we have no notes!
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No notes Found"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your `.xml` code for `ListView`. How to "add AdMob to listview"? Explain.

Comment: I want to add some banner ad like this https://i2.wp.com/raw.githubusercontent.com/clockbyte/admobadapter/master/screenshots/Screenshot_20160809-183435.png?resize=202%2C359&ssl=1

Comment: Here my .xml code

https://pastebin.com/5fgQusPM

Answer (score 0):

I assume by AdMob, you meant the Banner Ads? If I understand you correctly, you want to add Banner Ads into your `ListView` so they can be scrolled along with the 'Notes' in your List?

Banner Ads are shown through `AdView` which is essentially a `View`.

Therefore, what you need is to show an `AdView` instead of your View for your Notes in your `getView()` method when the position that's returned is one that's meant for your Ads.

This is more efficiently done through `RecyclerView` than `ListView` because `RecyclerView` has built-in implementations for showing a different set of Views based on their type.

**However, I DO have to warn you against doing this.**

**DO NOT** put AdMob ads in a scrollable list.

As quoted in AdMob Policies: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287

> Also, banner ads should not move as a user scrolls, as users may try to click on the menu but end up clicking on the ad accidentally instead. This specific implementation is against policy and we reserve the right to disable ad serving to your app.

AdMob banner ads shouldn't be scrollable by the user. Doing so will place you at a very high risk of having your app banned from receiving future ads from AdMob.

If it's serious enough, it can potentially cause your AdMob Account to be closed too.

The ads in scrollable lists that you see in other apps are most likely **not** getting their ads from AdMob, so they won't be in this type of risk.

If you still want to put banner ads in your scrollable list, but don't want to be in danger of getting banned, then I suggest you look at other Ad Providers other than AdMob. Check the policies for other Ad Providers and see if scrollable ads are prohibited by them. If they're not, then use them instead of AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple `xml` code to implement `ListView` and `AdMob banner` below `ListView`. Maybe this would be helpful for your purpose.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/Id" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Banner in center of list is not practical. It would look like something covering a list.